# Bootstrap: can't download the right version: the same code works differently with maxcdn version and official

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get [this code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAYAKd?editors=1100) to work.

It works fine when I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

`css` file. However, when I download Bootstrap from its official site (version 4-1): http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/, it doesn't work as expected: [my result](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGgopz).

Which the `maxcdn` site uses and where can I find it on official site?

I also wanted to customize a number of grid columns and tried to use sources from https://getbootstrap.com/customize/ link, but it seems it's possible to only customize version 3.3? Which doesn't work right either.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same CDN version and downloaded version of bootstrap. There are a lot of changes made in Bootstrap 4 from alpha version.  Read and view 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/... Here's the your code in Bootstrap version 4.1

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tribute Page | Tupac Shakur</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Details</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Awards</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">More Info</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```